# How to install rrdtool on centOS 4.4?

Tags: linux, centos, rrdtool

first I 'm trying to install rrdtool using:

```
 yum install rrdtool
```

but failed: no source?

so  I try to install it from source when I'm doing:

```
./configure
```

It says:

```
configure: error: Please fix the library issues listed above and try again.
```

some library issues it list to me:

```
configure: WARNING:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
* I could not find a working copy of glib-2.0. 

configure: WARNING:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
* I could not find a working copy of pangocairo. 


configure: WARNING:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
* I could not find a working copy of cairo-ps.
```

and cairo-png cairo-pdf etc...

But I have install thease libs before using :

anybody give a tutorial about install rrdtool on centOS 4?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not enough to install the libraries themselves, you must also install their development packages, suffixed by `-devel`.

Alternatively, you can install it from [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).